# How to use Bar Chart in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using AMChart library in swift.https://github.com/adventam10/AMChart

I created the bar chart. But I am not able to get the current result. Please help me!

Below image is my output:

[image]

But I need this type of output:

[image]

Below code is what I am using for BarChart

```
private func prepareDataList () {
    barDataList.removeAll()
    barColors.removeAll()
    var values = [Int]()
    values.removeAll()

    for i in 0..<colorArray.count {
        barColors.append(colorArray[i])

        let value = CGFloat(dataValues[i])
        values.append(Int(value))

        barDataList.append(values)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add:

```
pod 'Charts'
```

to your Podfile. "Charts" is the name of [the library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).

Comment: it is possible for BarChart library or not? with out using Charts library

Comment: what ?? I Cant Understand What U try to Say - Manohar